# How to Disable X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN for specific page

Tags: php, apache, x-frame-options

I am streaming videos, I have X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN enabled by default but I want to disable this header for my /embed codes.

I have tried to unset the header on my embed page before loading also tried to set another value but none of them worked;

```
header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT');

header_remove("X-Frame-Options");
```

I just want users to be able to embed only the iframe that has my video content just as youtube but nothing else. Is there any recommendations?

Thanks in advance!